# How to bind image to ImageButton dimensions?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridlayout, android-imagebutton

I'm having trouble inserting a large image into ImageButtons which are children of a GridLayout...

I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe board using a `GridLayout` which holds 9 identical `ImageButton`s.
I am using images larger than the buttons themselves and everytime I set an image to a button (using `setImageDrawable()`) the buttons expands to fit the image size...
My board looks like this:

```
 <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />

            <ImageButton
                ...
                />

            <ImageButton
                ...
                />

            [...]
   </GridLayout>
```

I've tried adjusting the image size according to the buttons' measurements but `getWidth()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` both return 0 (probably because the buttons don't have a defined widht and height).
Is there a way to make my image fit the button size without expanding the button itself?

Comment: use a framLayout as parant of both and make them match parent.

Comment: @mahdishahabazi do you mean wrapping each imagebutton in a frame layout or wrapping the whole grid?

Comment: no I mean instead of adding ```Imagebutton``` add ```FramLayout``` as ```GridLayout``` child then in it add ```Button``` and ```ImageView```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear not to have a set width of height on the imagebuttons. Adjust the width or height as needed.

Try

```
<ImageButton
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know the width and height shouldn't matter because they're overridden by rowWeight and columnWeight.
What will adding these attributes help me achieve?

Comment: I suspect by default it will be wrap_contents and can resize to the image size rather than constraining it so that the image is scales to the ImageButton size